# Recording guitar with rakarrack and audacity

Tags: soundcard

I'm trying to record my guitar with audacity and using rakarrack for effects.
I have an Lexicon Alpha plugged in with USB and my guitar plugged into the Lexicon Alpha.
I am able to record my guitar etc, but I cannot record my guitar through Rakarrack. JACK does not seem to recognise the Lexicon Alpha.

How can I make this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I will suggest you to use ardour to record your guitar with jack not audacity.

second, you need to specify your device in the jack interface, you have to select your usb hardware instead of the internal one.

let me know,
regards